# Finding local minimum between two peaks

Tags: pandas, time-series, sklearn-pandas, scikits

I have some time series data in Pandas where I need to extract specific local minimums from a column so I can use them as Features in a LSTM model. To visualize what I'm looking for I've attached a [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KL7YB.png), where the circled points are the values that I wish to locate.

The other red dots that you see at the bottom of the graph is my failed attempt of using "argrelextrema" with the following code:

```
#Trying to Locate Minimum Values
df['HKL Min'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.hkla.values, np.less_equal,order=50)[0]]['hkla']

#Plotting a range of values from dataset:
sns.lineplot(x=df.index[0:3000], y= 'hkla', data=df[0:3000], label='Hookload');
sns.scatterplot(x=df.index[0:3000], y= 'HKL Min', data=df[0:3000], s= 50, color ='red', label='HKL Min');
```

As you may notice, my column data has a repetitive pattern, and the points I wish to locate are the minimas found between two "peaks-pairs".Is there some existing functions in Python that can help me locate these specific points? Any form of help would be highly appreciated. I am also open to other suggestions that can solve my issue here...

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: Posting some sample data would be very useful here

Comment: I do not recall there being any such built in methods in either Numpy or Scipy.  However,  you should learn to code this bc it will come up many times. You can do it yourself using 1st and 2nd derivative tests, or lookup a Savitzky–Golay filter.

Comment: @perl My datasets are Confidential which is why I have not posted any sample data, I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @wbg I'm rather new to Python which is why I asked for a quick fix. I'll try using your recommended methods as well.

Comment: @W1nu It's fine, but you can normally take a small sample + obfuscate the data (reset dates to 1900-01-01, normalize values etc.), making it possible for others to test an approach, but not to extract any meaning from the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this with your data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema


np.random.seed(1234)
rs = np.random.randn(500)
xs = [0]
for r in rs:
    xs.append(xs[-1] * 0.999 + r)
df = pd.DataFrame(xs, columns=['point'])
```

which gives this data

```
point
0    0.000000
1    0.471435
2   -0.720012
3    0.713415
4    0.400050
..        ...
496  3.176240
497  3.007734
498  3.123841
499  1.045736
500  0.041935

[501 rows x 1 columns]
```

You can choose how often you want to mark a local ma or min by playing with a parameter:

```
n = 10

df['min'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.point.values, np.less_equal,
                    order=n)[0]]['point']
df['max'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.point.values, np.greater_equal,
                    order=n)[0]]['point']


plt.scatter(df.index, df['min'], c='r')
plt.scatter(df.index, df['max'], c='r')
plt.plot(df.index, df['point'])
plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Another choice for `n` might be (and it all depends on what you want):

```
n = 40

df['min'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.point.values, np.less_equal,
                    order=n)[0]]['point']
df['max'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.point.values, np.greater_equal,
                    order=n)[0]]['point']


plt.scatter(df.index, df['min'], c='r')
plt.scatter(df.index, df['max'], c='g')
plt.plot(df.index, df['point'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

To get a marking for which points actually where max and min, you can make a new df:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.T == df.T.max(), 1, 0),index=df.columns).T
```

which gives the information about which row in `df` is a maximum or a minimum. Otherwise, the original `df` contains that information in the created `min` and `max` columns, those instance that aren't `nan`

**EDIT: Finding peaks above threshold**

If you are intrested of peaks above a certain value, then you should use `find_peaks` in the following way:

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks 
peaks, _ = find_peaks(df['point'], height = 15)
plt.plot(df['point'])
plt.plot(peaks, df['point'][peaks], "x")
plt.show()
```

which will produce:

```
peaks,_


(array([304, 309, 314, 317, 324, 329, 333, 337, 343, 349, 352, 363, 366,
        369, 372, 374, 377, 379, 381, 383, 385, 387, 391, 394, 397, 400,
        403, 410, 413, 418, 424, 427, 430, 433, 436, 439, 442, 444, 448],
       dtype=int64),
 {'peak_heights': array([15.68868141, 15.97184882, 15.04790966, 15.6146908 , 16.49191501,
         18.0852033 , 18.11467247, 19.48469432, 21.32391722, 19.90407526,
         19.93683051, 24.40980129, 28.00319793, 26.1080406 , 24.44322213,
         23.16993982, 22.27505873, 21.47500832, 22.3236231 , 24.02484906,
         23.83727054, 24.32609486, 21.25365717, 21.10295203, 20.03162979,
         20.64021444, 19.78510855, 21.62624829, 22.34904425, 21.60431638,
         18.41968769, 18.24153961, 18.00747871, 18.02793964, 16.72552016,
         17.58573207, 16.90982675, 16.9905686 , 16.30563852])})
```

and graphically
[image]

Comment: this is in the ballpark of what I'm looking for. Is it possible to only use "argrelextrema" for a specific height? If I use your example, are there any way to only locate peaks where the
y-values > 15 ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem using the approach provided by @Serge de Gosson de Varennes. I switched out the "argrelextrema" with scipy "find_peaks()" as follows:

```
df['Min'] = df.iloc[find_peaks(-df.column[0:3000], height=(-350000,-250000), threshold = None,
                           distance=200, )[0]]['column']
```

The height input here gave me the option to choose an interval in the y-direction, which made it quite easy to detect the local minimas that I was looking for within said interval. When plotting the results like this:

```
plt.plot(df.index[0:3000], df.column[0:3000])
plt.plot(df.index, df['Min'],'ro', color = 'red', label = 'Min Values')
```

I got the following [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4edY1.png)

Thank you for the assistance!